# rails 4 find with include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have such relations:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization_type
  has_many :organization_type_links
end


class OrganizationType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizations
  has_many :organization_type_links
end


class OrganizationTypeLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :organization_type
end
```

and in table organizations i have field: organization_type_link_id
in table organization_type_links:   organization_type_id

how could i select all organization, where in table organization_type_links it's organization_type_id is some value?    In rails 3 i know ho to do this...

in 4th i try so:

```
Organization.includes(:organization_type_links).where(organization_type_id: params[:id])
```

but this doesn't fetch what i want to see...

Comment: What do you expect to see and what is the actual result?

Comment: @Agis result is nil, i expect to see result's of Organization, where organization_type_link.organization_type_id = 1

Comment: And what does `Organization.where(organization_type_id: 1)` returns?

Comment: @Agis table organizations didn't have such field...  Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'organizations.organization_type_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `organizations`.* FROM `organizations`  WHERE `organizations`.`organization_type_id` = 1 LIMIT 40 OFFSET 0

Comment: Have you run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: @Agis ofc! i did this

Comment: Something must be wrong in your migrations then. Based on your relations, `Organization` *should* have a foreign key column called `organization_type_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `joins` instead:

```
Organization.joins(:organization_type_links).where(organization_type_links: { organization_type_id: params[:id] })
```

Comment: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'organizations.organization_type_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `organizations`.* FROM `organizations` INNER JOIN `organization_type_links` ON `organization_type_links`.`organization_id` = `organizations`.`id` WHERE `organizations`.`organization_type_id` = '1' LIMIT 40 OFFSET 0